# How to use a model-view architecture with pyqtgraph plotting

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Is it possible to implement a model-view architecture with pyqtgraph? It seems like pyqtgraph forces you along a widget-centric approach (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html) in which each plotitem has its own scene?

It would be great if the ViewBox (see image below from docs -http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/plotting.html) would be an actual "view" of a scene, and the axis items around it would be dependent on that particular view. Therefore, if a number of PlotWidgets/PlotItems were displaying the same PlotDataItems at different zoom-levels, if you changed the zorder or scaled an item this would be shown on all the PlotItems without resorting to sending signals etc between PlotItems.

To do this does the ViewBox have to be an embedded GraphicsView? Or is it possible to have a PlotItem on multiple GraphicsViews?

Thanks!

Some other reference links:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html

[image]

Comment: I have a minor question associated with this -- I looked up pyqtgraph today and it states that it is based on pyqt4 which means its based on python 2.7 and one of these stopped being supported in Dec 2015 and the other will stop being supported in January 2020 --- so will or does pyqtgraph have a version that is based on pyqt5 and python 3.x ??  And if not why use something that is going to be completely unsupported come this January??

Comment: It works with pyqt5 and python 3 for me. I'm definitely not an expert but I think (some) of the code to enable pyqtgraph to work with both is here: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/pyqtgraph/Qt.py#L173

Comment: Okay thanks for that information but perhaps it is something you might want to consider and/or dig a little deeper into because eventually once they both are no longer supported its just a matter of time before they stop working altogether or at least that has been my experience.

Comment: @DennisJensen: pyqtgraph supports both Python 2 and 3, can work transparently with PySide or Qt, both 4 and 5. As long as you import the right PyQt/PySide version in advance, pyqtgraph will automatically use that version..

Comment: @Cornspierre QGraphicsItems cannot be added to more than one scene at once. You *could* add the same scene to different views, but it's not that easy: pyqtgraph painting, transformations and clipping would be applied to the new view too, making almost useless to try this approach.

Comment: @musicamante Yes that's what I meant by pyqtgraph seeming to force you down an approach of one view for one scene... I was hoping you could do something like replacing the ViewBox with an embedded view (https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/graphicsview.html#embedded-widget-support), but I tried to understand how pyqtgraph implements all the transformations and rendering etc and kind of gave up...

Comment: Yes, you can also embed a QGraphicsView within a QGraphicsProxyWidget and add it to another QGraphicsScene (I've done it in the past), but pyqtgraph classes are a bit complex and not designed for this kind of interoperability, so I think that it'll take less efforts to create your own subclass of PlotItem (using a subclass of ViewBox, to better interface with its signals/slots and properties) than using a graphics proxy widget.